# how to get the form values in ionic 3

Tags: html, forms, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a form. but how to get selected values in function.

i used dropdown, in that selected value need to send to the function.

**product_option[{{tms.productoption_id}}],
optnslist.product_optionvalue_id** this two value need to send to function

Html code:

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="logForm(myfoem)">
  <ion-grid  *ngIf="varibleprd == 'variable'">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let tms of optionprd;">
  <ion-label>{{tms.option_name}}:</ion-label>
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="tms.option_name" name="product_option[{{tms.productoption_id}}]"> 

     <ion-option *ngFor="let optnslist of tms.optionvalue" [value]="optnslist.product_optionvalue_id">{{optnslist.optionvalue_name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
 </ion-item>
 </ion-grid>

 <button block><ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon></button>
   </form>
```

and Ts code:

```
   export class ProductdetailPage {
   frmdata:any;
   subfrmdata:any;

 logForm(subfrmdata){
  this.frmdata=subfrmdata.value;
  console.log(this.frmdata);
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below. This might help you:-

**In HTML file**

```
<ion-option *ngFor="let optnslist of tms.optionvalue" [value]="optnslist.product_optionvalue_id" 
(ionSelect)="logForm(product_option[tms.productoption_id], optnslist.product_optionvalue_id);">
{{optnslist.optionvalue_name}}</ion-option>
```

Then in the ts file:-

```
logForm(productoption_id, product_optionvalue_id){
  // Do the needful
}
```